# Connect two point in page using short ruler

Tags: geometry

There is problem that my friend and me don't have solution for it. the problem is that can we connect to point in page with straight line using a ruler that it length is too much shorter than distance of two given point? if we can't do this prove that it is impossible.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a pair of compasses?

Comment: You can just put the ruler on $A$, "aim" at $B$, mark a new point on the $AB$ line a little closer to $B$ and continue this way.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio it won't be a straight line

Comment: @WillBrooks no just a short ruler

Comment: Are you allowed to fold the paper?

Comment: @columbus8myhw no

Comment: Then I honestly don't think it's possible. ... Where did this problem come up?

Comment: This question is pretty interesting and practical. There might be a solution with folding the paper.